# Latin, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese and French number words from eleven to nineteen - history of a bizarre, inconsistent construction

Tags: historical-linguistics, language-change, comparative-linguistics, romance-languages, numerals

Following [Sklivvz's advice](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/italian-number-words-from-eleven-to-nineteen-history-of-a-bizarre-inconsisten), I propose here a question I made in Italian Language. Because I am not sure how I should do this, I will just copy/paste the whole lot.

Let's count in Latin from one to twenty:

> ūnus/ūna/ūnum, duo/duae/duo, trēs/tria, quattuor, quīnque, sex, septem, octō, novem, decem,
>
> ūndecim, duodecim, tredecim, quattuordecim, quīndecim, sēdecim, septendecim, duodēvīgintī, ūndēvīgintī, vīgintī

As pointed out by [symbiotech](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/italian-number-words-from-eleven-to-nineteen-history-of-a-bizarre-inconsisten), "octodecim" and "novemdecim" were also used in Latin, but they didn't survive. On the other hand, as pointed out by [martina](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/italian-number-words-from-eleven-to-nineteen-history-of-a-bizarre-inconsisten), "[dĕcem (et) sĕptem](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=diciassette)" was also a common form for "septemdĕcim".

In Attic Greek it was:

> ΕΙΣ/ΜΙΑ/ΕΝ (heis/mia/en), ΔΥΟ (dúō), ΤΡΕΙΣ/ΤΡΙΑ (treis/tria), ΤΕΤΤΑΡΕΣ/ΤΕΤΤΑΡΑ (téttares/téttara), ΠΕΝΤΕ (pénte), ΕΞ (héx), ΕΠΤΑ (heptá), ΟΚΤΩ (oktṓ), ΕΝΝΕΑ (ennéa), ΔΕΚΑ (déka),
>
> ΕΝΔΕΚΑ (héndeka), ΔΩΔΕΚΑ (dódeka), ΤΡΕΙΣΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (treiskaídeka), ΤΕΤΤΑΡΕΣ ΚΑΙ ΔΕΚΑ (téttares kaì déka), ΠΕΝΤΕΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (pentekaídeka), ΕΚΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (hekkaídeka), ΕΠΤΑΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (heptakaídeka), ΟΚΤΩΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (oktōkaídeka), ΕΝΝΕΑΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (enneakaídeka), ΕΙΚΟΣΙ(Ν) (eíkosi(n))

Now let's count in Italian

> uno, due, tre, quattro, cinque, sei, sette, otto, nove, dieci,
>
> undici, dodici, tredici, quattordici, quindici, sedici, diciassette,
> diciotto, diciannove, venti.

But numbers from eleven to twenty could also have been, just hypothetically of course (adding accents for clarity's sake):

> diciùno, diciaddùe, diciattré, diciacquàttro, diciaccìnque, diciassèi, diciassètte, diciòtto, diciannòve, venti

or

> undici, dodici, tredici, quattordici, quindici, sedici, settèndici, ottòdici, novèndici, venti.

In Spanish it is:

> uno, dos, tres, cuatro, cinco, seis, siete, ocho, nueve, diez,
>
> once, doce, trece, catorce, quince, dieciseis, diecisiete, dieciocho, diecinueve, veinte

In Portuguese:

> um, dois, três, quarto, cinco, seis, sete, oito, nove, dez,
>
> onze, doze, treze, catorze/quatorze, quinze, dezasseis/dezesseis, dezessete/dezessete, dezoito, dezenove/dezenove, vinte

In French:

> un, deux, trois, quatre, cinq, six, sept, huit, neuf, dix,
>
> onze, douze, treize, quatorze, quinze, seize, dix-sept, dix-huit, dix-neuf, vingt

Following [martina's hint](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/italian-number-words-from-eleven-to-nineteen-history-of-a-bizarre-inconsisten) here are the number words from one to twenty in Romanian:

> unu, doi, trei, patru, cinci, şase, şapte, opt, nouă, zece,
>
> unsprezece, doisprezece, treisprezece, paisprezece, cincisprezece, şaisprezece, şaptesprezece, optsprezece, nouăsprezece, douăzeci

I find Latin, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese and French constructions for number words bizarre and inconsistent (whereas in Romanian it seems they are perfectly consistent as well as in Ancient Greek). Is there any academic work on the history of number words in Latin/Italian/Spanish/Portuguese/French where the origin of number words from eleven to nineteen is tracked down, documented, explained, discussed?

Please note [the answer by symbiotech in the original post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/italian-number-words-from-eleven-to-nineteen-history-of-a-bizarre-inconsisten) - I am not able to check it, perhaps someone in here can?

Comment: In Romanian the two seemingly irregular numbers, 14 (_paisprezece_ vs. _patru_, "4") and 16 (_şaisprezece_ vs. _şase_, "6") have perfectly regular variants _patrusprezece_ (14) and _şasesprezece_ (16).

Comment: I don't know any work about this, but I think inconsistencies in that number range make sense for every superstrate language. The numbers up to 12 were used so much in daily commerce that everybody knew them correctly. Very large numbers were rarely used, and the people using them mostly knew the language well. But in the medium range, innovations from L2 speakers choosing workarounds (forming numbers according to their L1 patterns, or using ad hoc methods) when they didn't know the L2 patterns, seem most likely to have occurred frequently enough to spread.

Comment: This question has been asked for [Italian](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/italian-number-words-from-eleven-to-nineteen-history-of-a-bizarre-inconsisten), [Spanish](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3969/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-los-nombres-de-los-n%C3%BAmeros), [French](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/878/treize-quatorze-quinze-seize), [Portuguese](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4/por-que-os-n%C3%BAmeros-onze-ao-quinze-n%C3%A3o-se-escreve-como-uma-composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-deze). No answer so far explains the inconsistencies.

Comment: The inconsistencies are because they're different languages with different speakers. What you have is several colliding and contrasting forms, and no surprise that they work it out differently in different languages and cultures, at different times and places. The 10-20 decade is often irregular, in many languages, so that's not surprising, either. There's the Latin (and Latin-descended) forms like _quatorze, quattordici,_ there's the 'ten-and-seven' pattern, with a conjunction, like _dieciseis_, the reverse Greek 'seven-and-ten' pattern, and the '20-minus 2' pattern, like _duodēvīgintī_.

Comment: Germanic languages change after 12. Traditional Welsh is even more complicated than Romance: _un ar ddeg_ (one on ten), _dau ar ddeg_, _tri ar ddeg_, _pedwar ar ddeg_, _pymtheg_ (contraction of _pymp deg_, 5 10), _un ar bymtheg_ (one on fifteen), _dau ar bymtheg_, _deunaw_ (two nine!), _pedwar ar bymtheg_, _ugain_.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9811/707).

Answer (score 9):

There are forces driving language evolution, and we see two of them at work here.

The first driving force is **Regularisation**. The irregular pattern of latin (indicated by duodeviginti and undeviginti, showing a counting down from 20 instead of counting up from 10) wasn't able to resist this driving force and all quoted modern Romance languages use "counting up from 10", i.e. a more regular pattern.

The second driving force is **Sound Change**. At some time and for some descendants of latin, the successors of sedecim and septemdecim became too similar in sound (something like *sedeci and *seddeci), therefore more distinctive forms for the two different numbers were needed.

Different dialects/languages reacted differently to the pressure of theses two forces (evolution is unpredictable, after all). French and Italian made 16 and 17 maximally different (seize vs. dix-sept). Spanish and Portuguese chose a more regular, but still distinct enough pattern (dieciseis and diecisiete). Romanian is the odd Romance language out, where Sound Change didn't put up much pressure and the old latin forms of 16 and 17 are pretty well preserved (şaisprezece and şaptesprezece). Romanian was than able to develop a completely regular pattern up to 19 (nouăsprezece).

ADDITION: In Romanian there is still something left to explain: Romanian has acquired an infix -spre- "to" not present in Latin or the other Romance languages. This exhibits a third driving force to language evolution, the **influence of other languages**. I daren't decide whether it is the consequence of a Dacian *substrat* or a Slavonic or Albanian *adstrat*. At least, Albanian numerals (gjashtëmbëdhjetë "16" with -bë- inserted) and Bulgarian numerals (шестна́десет (šestnádeset) "16" with -ná- inserted) show the same pattern of formation.

Comment: You answer is right since it shows the linguistic laws governing the changes. However, it does not answer the original question which asks for an *academic work* where the phenomenon of irregular numerals have been covered for *all* listed languages. Also, the bounty says, *A detailed canonical answer is required*. Would you please consider expanding your answer to make it a more fundamental research? You seem to have a good start so far.

Comment: @bytebuster You get what you pay for. This is free. For research in printed books and journals for references, visit a university library and do it yourself (it may take some weeks). I'm sure you will find some references given enough time.

Comment: The only currency within StackExchange network is reputation points. Someone who wants to earn money may need to find another network. Yes, a good answer to this question, indeed, worth some weeks of research. *Another* answer, I mean.

Comment: jknappen, I hope I'm not intruding in this thread, I really like your answer regarding numerals. But there's something in Romanian that I need to point out. The infix is "spre" (same pronounciation as "pre", just add "s" in front), which means "to", so "unsprezece" is "one-to-ten", "doisprezece" (or "douăsprezece", the feminine variant) is "two-to-ten", "treisprezece" is "three-to-ten", "patrusprezece" ("paisprezece" tends to be found in informal usage, just like "șasesprezece" versus "șaisprezece") is "four-to-ten" and so on. I'm a native Romanian speaker.

Comment: AFAIK Romanian _unsprezece_, _doisprezece_ are a clear influence of the Slavic adstrat. Historically, Slavic 11-19 are constructed as "one-on-ten", "two-on-ten" up to "nine-on-ten" (clearly visible e.g. in Russian: _odinnadcať_ < _odin-na-desať_ or your Bulgarian example _šest-na-deset_ = "six-on-ten"). Romanian seems to have adopted this: _unsprezece_ < _unum-super-decem_. While Romanian _spre_ changed meaning to "to", it stems from Latin _super_ ("on" or "over").